# Regular expression to extract paragraph from the page below

Tags: java, regex, itext

I have this text that I have extracted from a pdf using iText and placed into a String variable:

```
(1) A a, — al'-fah; of Hebrew origin; the first letter of the alphabet;
figurative only (from its use as a numeral) the first: — Alpha.
Often used (usually ajn an, before a vowel) also in composition
(as a contraction from (427) (a]neu,)) in the sense of privation;
so in many words beginning with this letter; occasionally in the
sense of union (as a contraction of (260) (a[ma)).
(2) ÆAarw>n, — ah-ar-ohn'; of Hebrew origin [Hebrew {175}
('Aharown)]; Aaron, the brother of Moses: — Aaron.
(3) ÆAbaddw>n, — ab-ad-dohn'; of Hebrew origin [Hebrew {11}
('abaddown)]; a destroying angel: — Abaddon.
(4) ajbarh>v, — ab-ar-ace'; from (1) (a) (as a negative particle) and (922)
(ba>rov); weightless, i.e. (figurative) not burdensome: — from
being burdensome.
(5) ÆAbba~, — ab-bah'; of Chaldee origin [Hebrew {2} ('ab (Chaldee))];
father (as a vocative): — Abba.
(6) &Abel, — ab'-el; of Hebrew origin [Hebrew {1893} (Hebel)]; Abel,
the son of Adam: — Abel.
(7) ÆAbia>, — ab-ee-ah'; of Hebrew origin [Hebrew {29} ('Abiyah)];
Abijah, the name of two Israelites: — Abia.
(8) ÆAbia>qar, — ab-ee-ath'-ar; of Hebrew origin [Hebrew {54}
('Ebyathar)]; Abiathar, an Israelite: — Abiathar.
(9) ÆAbilhnh>, — ab-ee-lay-nay'; of foreign origin [compare Hebrew {58}
('abel)]; Abilene, a region of Syria: — Abilene.
(10) ÆAbiou>d, — ab-ee-ood'; of Hebrew origin [Hebrew {31}
('Abiyhuwd)]; Abihud, an Israelite: — Abiud.
```

The paragraphs in the string begin with `([0-9])` as in `(9)` or `(5)` and I want to extract each paragraph that begins with this character sequence using `pagestring.split("regex")`. Can some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This avoids splitting on "(999)" embedded in the text. It is based on the assumption that a line end precedes the parenthesized number that indicates the start of a paragraph. Also note that the sample text produces an empty "paragraph" from no text preceding the first parenthesized number - therefore the if statement.

```
  String text = ...;
  String[] paras = text.split( "(?<=(^|\\n))\\(\\d+\\)" );
  for( String para: paras ){
      if( para.length() > 0 ){
          System.out.println( "Para: " + para );
      }
  }
```

Comment: awesome!  Is there a tutorial or guide you can recommend because regular expressions really mess me up?

Comment: I've learned regexes ages ago, so I can't really recommend a tutorial. But http://regexcrossword.com/ provides an entertaining way of learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex `"[\n|.]\\([0-9]{1,2}\\)"` with the split method and it will extract all the paragraphs from your text (including numbers from 0 to 99):

```
String[] parts=st.split("[\n|.]\\([0-9]{1,2}\\)");
```

> `[\n|.]`: to consider only the **new paragraphs** and *ignore* `(n)` in the pragraphs text.
>
> `\\([0-9]{1,2}\\)`: to match any group of **one** or **two** digits inside **()**.

Here is [**the working DEMO**](https://ideone.com/fESXYi), giving an array containing all the paragraphs.

See the [**Java Regex Pattern**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for further information about the use of regex.